# Suppress the virtual touch screen Windows keyboard in a WPF full screen application

Tags: wpf, keyboard, virtual, microsoft.ink

We have a full screen application developed in WPF that will be used on a touch interface.  As part of this project I developed a styled virtual keyboard that will be used to input when the application is run on a touch device.  Everything works great except for the appearance of the Windows Virtual Keyboard input icon appearing when a user clicks on a textbox (for instance).

What we would like to do is to suppress the Windows keyboard from activating when the user grabs focus on "specific" input controls.  We may still want the keyboard on other input areas such as open or file save dialogs so disabling the keyboard for the application or globally is not an option.

I have found documentation on MSDN that suggests a possible solution would be to use TextInputPanel from the Microsoft.Ink namespace.  However, that last version of that code is 3.5 (this is a 4.0 app) and I cant seem to find the dll anywhere it should be.

Any suggestions at this point would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You can either user on focus on each of the Input controls of ur application which may be very costly for you.... Other way which is more sophisticated is Using System Hooks to get the Caret--- from which u can get either the caret is enable or disable... so whenever the caret is enabled you have to make the VKeyboard enable... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You simply disable it in the corresponding menu:

Start button > Control Panel > classic view > Ease of Access > click Use the computer without a mouse or keyboard > UN-check Use ON-screen Keyboard > Save

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-the-on-screen-keyboard/ce752b42-f8a5-4693-957c-c7acef0d80b3

Comment: this does not answer the question, the question was about the keyboard icon, which is not controlled by this setting